# Differential entropy of random Gibbs measure

Tags: pr.probability, entropy, statistical-physics

There is a question I have been wondering about for a while, which I have thus far not been able to resolve. The problem revolves around random Gibbs measures. I am not very well-versed in the more theoretical side of probability theory, so I apologize for any messy terminology.

Let $S$ be a finite set. Let $w$ be a vector of $m$ real numbers taking values in a set $E$, and let $J(x \mid w)$ be a non-negative function linear in $w$, assigning a value to each $x \in S$. Finally, let $\lambda \geq 0$ be a constant. We define for each $w$ and $\lambda$ a Gibbs measure on $S$ as

$$
\pi_\lambda(x \mid w) = \frac{e^{-\lambda J(x, w)}}{\sum_{y \in S} e^{-\lambda J(y, w)}} = \frac{e^{-\lambda J(x, w)}}{Z_\lambda(w)},
$$

where $Z_\lambda(w) = \sum_{y \in S} e^{-\lambda J(x, w)}$.

Now suppose that $w$ is not fixed, but is a random variable $W$ sampled from some density $\mu$. Then $\pi_\lambda(x \mid W)$ is a random Gibbs measure. We can then define the joint density of $x$ and $W$:

$$
\pi_\lambda(x, w) = \pi_\lambda(x \mid w)\mu(w).
$$

I want to know what happens to the differential entropy of the joint random variables $(X, W)$:

$$
H_\mu(\pi_\lambda) = -\int_E\sum_{x \in S} \pi_\lambda(x, w)\mu(w) \ln(\pi_\lambda(x, w)\mu(w)) dw.
$$

Specifically, I want to relate the quantities $H_\mu(\pi_\lambda)$ and $H_{\nu_\lambda}(\pi_\lambda)$, where $\nu_\lambda(w) = \mu(w)Z_\lambda(w)/\mathbb{E}_\mu(Z_\lambda(W))$ (here, $\mathbb{E}_\mu$ denotes the expected value w.r.t. $\mu$). To make some things more concrete, let's say that $\mu$ is the uniform distribution on $[0, 1]^m$.

These quantities have an interpretation from physics, which I will put below the main post. My interest, however, comes from combinatorial optimization, not physics.

From numerical experiments, it seems that at least in the above setting, $H_\mu(\pi_\lambda) \geq H_{\nu_\lambda}(\pi_\lambda)$ for all $\lambda$, with equality iff $\lambda = 0$. The same seems to be true when $\mu$ is a product of identical Gaussians. But because the Gibbs measure $\pi_\lambda(x, w)$ is a pretty cumbersome object, I haven't been able to prove this inequality. The only thing I can show is that $H_{\nu_\lambda}(\pi_\lambda)$ becomes negative for $\lambda$ above some threshold, while $H_\mu(\pi_\lambda) \geq 0$ always; thus the inequality holds above this threshold. But I'd like to show it holds for all $\lambda$.

I'm asking here because all of this is somewhat outside of my field, so I want to make sure that there isn't some known result or method that I am missing.

---

For the physics interpretation: this whole formalism is essentially the formalism of spin glasses and disordered systems. The equivalent of the variables $W$ are then the couplings between different spins (uniform in my setting, Gaussian for spin glasses). The density $\pi_\lambda(x, w)\mu(w)$ is then the "quenched" density, corresponding to drawing the variables $W$ first and letting the system reach thermal equilibrium with $W$ frozen, while $\pi_\lambda(x, w)\nu_\lambda(w)$ is the "annealed" density, corresponding to letting the variables $W$ equilibrate together with $x$.